# NordVPN local network addresses not reachable when connected

Tags: networking, vpn, ping

I'm using `nordvpn` CLI on Ubuntu for quite a while but, since a few days, when I'm trying to reach any other client in my local network, I'm getting e.g. the following problem:

```
$ ping 192.168.178.1
PING 192.168.178.1 (192.168.178.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

where `192.168.178.1` is my router. When I disconnect from NordVPN I can reach other clients again.

I already read about similar problems being related to the `nordvpn killswitch`, but it is disabled and I also tried to enable and then to disable it.
I also tried to disable the `ufw`, and reinstalled `nordvpn` but that didn't help either.

As it might be helpful, here my `nordvpn settings`:

```
$ nordvpn settings
Technology: OpenVPN
Protocol: UDP
Kill Switch: disabled
CyberSec: disabled
Obfuscate: disabled
Notify: enabled
Auto-connect: disabled
DNS: disabled
```

Might be that it's something quite stupid or easy to resolve, but I'm struggling with that for a few days now.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Same same. I thought maybe it was a bug in the app, but 3.8.5 is the same.

My settings (which worked several nordvpn app versions ago):

```
Technology: NordLynx
Kill Switch: disabled
CyberSec: disabled
Notify: enabled
Auto-connect: enabled
DNS: 1.0.0.1, 1.1.1.1
```

**Resolution** (Later)

Hahaha! Got it! Whitelist your internal. Mine is `192.168.2.xxx`, adjust yours accordingly.

```
nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.2.0/24
```

Comment: Great, that really worked! Thank you.

Though I'm wondering that it worked before and they changed it without saying something...

Comment: wow so much nonsense about this on searches and only 2 upvotes on the correct answer! not many people running nord and sshing around on linux eh :(

Thanks so much!! Wish they did this automatically since its kind of expected ..

Comment: Thank you, you're the man!

Comment: nordvpn does not make this obvious or easy.  First, the whitelist command is buried in a set of recommended provisioning steps in the installation guide.  Second it provides the "allowlisting" function and the "whitelist" token is not found in the nordvpn help section.  Anyway, this provides the functionality I need.

Comment: worked like a charm. this should be accepted, one-liner answer.

Answer (score 8):

Whitelisting my subnets only allowed me to make connections using IP addresses. I'm lazy and prefer hostnames. So I had to add my DNS server (my router) to the Nordvpn configuration. My router is at 192.168.50.1. So I used the command
`nordvpn set dns 192.168.50.1`

Comment: In my case `localhost` was blocked but `127.0.0.1` worked.